# Running the Following Playbook syntax appears to be correct but getting following ERROR!- 'blockinfile' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

Running the Following Playbook syntax appears to be correct but getting following ERROR!

```
ERROR! 'blockinfile' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

The error appears to have been in `/root/playbook1.yml`: line 2, column 3,     but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
---
- name: insertupdate
  ^ here
```

My Playbook file code is:

```
---
- name: insertupdate
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/network/interfaces
    block: |
      iface eth2 inet static
          address 192.168.0.1
          netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36468870/running-the-following-playbook-syntax-appears-to-be-correct-but-getting-followin

Found the solution in the above Url, i am missing "tasks" in my play.